# (jQuery) Apply the title that is inside an element as an aria-label to the link that is inside the div and does not contain an aria label

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML

```
<div class="box-container">
 <a href="#"></a>
 <h3 class="box-title">Title 1</h3>
</div>
<div class="box-container">
 <a href="#"></a>
 <h3 class="box-title">Title 2</h3>
</div>
    <div class="box-container">
 <a href="#"></a>
 <h3 class="box-title">Title 3</h3>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
 $('a:not([aria-label])').attr('aria-label', function() {
      var txt = $(".box-container > .box-title").text();
      $(this).attr("aria-label", txt);
  });
```

The problem is that the above div appears 3 times inside the whole page, so the code above will return and apply as an aria-label in the link, all the titles that have these classes.
Example: aria-label="Title element 1Title element 2Title element3"

So I am trying to figure out why the above does not apply to the link of the div, the specific  .box-title class for each div, only.

What I try to achieve and $(this) does not work properly:

```
  <div class="box-container">
     <a href="#" aria-label="Title 1"></a>
     <h3 class="box-title">Title 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container">
     <a href="#" aria-label="Title 2"></a>
     <h3 class="box-title">Title 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container">
     <a href="#" aria-label="Title 3"></a>
     <h3 class="box-title">Title 3</h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: `var txt = $(this).next('.box-title').text();` https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: @GrafiCode This worked for me. You can provide it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-container">
 <a href="#"></a>
 <h3 class="box-title">Title 1</h3>
</div>
<div class="box-container">
 <a href="#"></a>
 <h3 class="box-title">Title 2</h3>
</div>
    <div class="box-container">
 <a href="#"></a>
 <h3 class="box-title">Title 3</h3>
</div>

<script>
    $('a:not([aria-label])').attr('aria-label', function() {
      var txt = $(this).parent().find(".box-title").text();
      $(this).attr("aria-label", txt);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This also worked. But what is the difference between your answer and the answer that GrafiCode commented on? Is any of these a best practice or works better?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).